# Web service request from asp.net 4.5 application over SSL

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to request a web service over ssl from an asp.net 4.5 application. I was issued a pkcs #12 certificate by the entity that host the web service and have installed it under Trusted Root Certification Authorities in my development box.
I can add the web reference to the web service from Visual Studio but when i make a service request i get the following error message:

There was no endpoint listening at http://secure.aduana.gov.py/wsaaserver/Server that could accept the message. The cause is usually an incorrect address or SOAP action.

The code is:

```
protected void Button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    py.gov.aduana.secure.WsaaServerBeanService proxy = new py.gov.aduana.secure.WsaaServerBeanService();
    var result = proxy.loginCms( "test" );
    Response.Write( result );
}
```

The question in short:
Apart from installing the certificate as i did, do i need to send the certificate in tehe code with the request ?

Edit:
I changed my code to pass the certificate by code like

```
webServiceClient = new WsaaServerBeanClient( WebSvcEndpointConfigurationName, new EndpointAddress( webSvcEndpointAddress ) );
            var cert = GetCertificateByThumbprint( webSvcCertificateThumbPrint, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            if ( null == cert )                     
                return;           

webServiceClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

private X509Certificate2 GetCertificateByThumbprint( string certificateThumbPrint, StoreLocation certificateStoreLocation ) {
    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

    X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store( certificateStoreLocation );
    certificateStore.Open( OpenFlags.ReadOnly );


    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certificateStore.Certificates;
    foreach ( X509Certificate2 cert in certCollection ) {
        if ( cert.Thumbprint != null && cert.Thumbprint.Equals( certificateThumbPrint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) {
            certificate = cert;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( certificate == null ) {
        Label1.Text = string.Format("Certificate with thumbprint {0} not found", certificateThumbPrint );
    }

    return certificate;
}
```

But the certificate is not retrieved from the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your url is wrong.  Shouldn't it be "https://"?  I get a better error message if I go to the SSL url in my browser.

**Edit:**

If I go to http://secure.aduana.gov.py/wsaaserver/Server, I get a 404 error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /wsaaserver/Server was not found on this server.
```

But if I go to the SSL version at https://secure.aduana.gov.py/wsaaserver/Server, I get this message:

```
HTTP GET not supported
```

Just based on the error message, I think the SSL version is much more likely the correct URL to be using.

Comment: That is the address generated by the reference for the end point Endpoint address="http://secure.aduana.gov.py/wsaaserver/Server". I cannot see how it can be wrong.

Comment: I have seen this kind of mistake in other web service references.  It should be trivial for you to change the URL in the `reference.cs` file and try it.

Comment: Well, I changes to https and also configure the security mode to Transport in order to use https and i get the same original error message.